# Android NFC bluetooth Handover

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc

I found an  uncompleted example over http://fupeg.blogspot.com/search/label/nfc but i am unable to understand the method  startBluetooth() that it is not mentioned in the example.

So if any one can share an example of "NFC to Bluetooth Handover in android"?.

Answer (score 0):

The `startBluetooth(msg)` method should compare the timestamaps as discussed in the article and decide which phone should act as client or server. Next is to decode the Bluetooth address and the service UUID from the NDEF message. Then initiate either the `ServerThread` or `ClientThread` based on the timestamp and start them. This piece if code is missing, just as well as the `CommThread` class, that handles the socket communications on both side.

By the way this is a very good example for the NFC Bluetooth handover, even with omitting the utility functions. I highlights the key NFC and Bluetooth operations very well.

Comment: How do I find the UUID of my device to send it to the other device during handoff??